# How to check whether node $N is present in the sequence-of-nodes $S in XQuery?

Tags: xml, function, xpath, xquery

I know each variable in XQuery which takes an XPath expression can consist of a set of nodes

```
let $x := //cities[@population > '50000']//*
```

Or

```
let $y := //something/following::*
```

I would like to know is there a boolean function to check if `$z` belongs to these sets of nodes, for example `$x` or `$y`?

If no, then how can I declare such function to take two variables and return true if the first variable (sequence of nodes ) include the second (a node or sequence of nodes)

for a particular purpose I did the following test:

```
declare function local:inside($y,$x) as xs:boolean
{
  let $r :=  ? (: want to know if $y include $x or not :)
  return $r
};
let $db := doc('products.xq')
let $items := $db/item//*
let $pricesInItems := $db//price[$items//.]   (: $db//price[local:inside($items, .)] :)
                    (: ^ it doesn't work, by the way :)
return $pricesInItems
```

for this database:

```
<page>
  <products> 
      <item foo="f1"> 
          <price>100 </price> 
      </item>  
        <item foo="f2"> 
          <price>200 </price> 
      </item>  
  </products>
  <price>300 </price>
</page>
```

A predicate expression or a function which selects all prices where are inside `$db/item//*`. Please note this is just an example, I would like to have a general membership function or predicate expression which works for any two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches to test whether node $N is present in the sequence-of-nodes $S:

(a) `exists($S intersect $N)`

The `exists()` is redundant if used in a boolean context, e.g. you can write `if($S intersect $N)`

(b) `exists($S[. is $N])`

(Similarly, in a boolean context you can write `if($S[. is $N])`

Comment: Excuse me why this code doesn't work? `let $y := $db//item//*
let $z := $db//price[exists($y intersect .)]` according to the database in question $z should return two price nodes inside the item nodes, but it returns nothing

Comment: Thanks, it's strange! I think it works now. maybe I did a mistake before

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `=` operator, it will use set-based logic. For example:

```
let $set := (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
return ((6 = $set), (7 = $set))

=> (true(), false())
```

The same applies for comparisons across two sets:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4) = (4, 5, 6)
=> true()
```

Comment: What if a set is a collection of nodes selected by an XPath expression? please reconsider my revised question

Comment: Wrong answer, @Ahmad is interested in testing membership of a set of nodes, not atomic values.